# How to include a space in a tolog query using ontopia - omnigator

Tags: ontopia, tolog

I'm trying to write an ontopia tolog query with the test data set of ItalianOpera.  I am trying to query on type 'TV organization'.  I've tried `instance-of($TOPIC, TV company)?` which gives "Error: No object for TV"  I've tried `instance-of($TOPIC, "TV company")?` which gives Error: Predicate instance-of received a string as argument 2, but requires a topic.  I've tried `instance-of($TOPIC, 'TV company')?` which gives Error: Illegal character <'> at 1:20 and I've tried with backquotes which gives the same error.

So the question remains, how do I include a space in a tolog query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I was doing 3 things wrong:
1st: the tutorial shows 'TV company' as a type, but the italianOpera.ltm file now uses 'Boadcasting company' as the type

2nd: The queries need to be all lower case

3rd: spaces should be replaced by a hyphen

So the tolog query is `instance-of($TOPIC, broadcasting-company)?`

I hope this helps someone.